# Approximation using derivatives

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, approximation

I'm doing approximations using differentiation in one of my classes and was tasked to do the following exercise:

$$
\int_0^x \frac{e^{-t}}{t^{2}+0.51}dt
$$

if $x$ changes from $0.7$ to $0.71$.

My textbook has a very bad explanation of similar problems (if you can even consider them explanations) so I am a bit confused. I did the following:

$$
\Delta f=f(0.7)-f(0.71)
$$
$$
\Delta f\cong df=\frac{e^{-x}}{x^2+0.51}dx
$$

with $x=0.7$ and $dx=0.01$

$$\Rightarrow \Delta f\cong \frac{0.01e^{-0.7}}{0.49+0.51}=\frac{1}{100e^{0.7}}$$

The next step would be to estimate the value of my answer. However, I feel like I've done something wrong and that I should use the same method in such a way to avoid doing two approximations which greatly affect the accuracy of my method.

Can anyone tell me if my approach is correct?

P.S. I would use the Taylor Expansions of $e^x$ to approximate the value of $e^{0.7}$ since a linear approximation at $a=0$ would harm my approximation even more.

For those interested, this is the examples my textbook gives: [image]

And also this one:
[image]

Images were taken from MATHEMATICAL METHODS IN
THE PHYSICAL SCIENCES, 3rd ed by MARY L. BOAS.

Comment: You can get a better approximation of the integral by taking $0.01 * f(0.705)$. By taking the central value the accuracy increases a lot.

Comment: @M.Wind if I were to do that the calculation would be more complicated. The point of the exercise is to find a way to approximate while still being convenient.

Comment: Use a pocket calculator. Then it makes no difference whether you type in $0.7$ or $0.705$.

Comment: @M.Wind Haha I would, but if the exam is without a calculator then I cannot. These problems are required to be done without a computer (calculators included).

Comment: Well, they can't expect you to evaluate $e^{-0.7}$ with some degree of accuracy !?

Comment: @M.Wind that's why I'm confused, since I'm new to this I don't know how far should I go.

Comment: In my opinion $0.01 e^{-0.7}$ is a perfectly satisfactory answer. No need to go further.